# Multiple vs single container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I want to put nginx in front of multiple node.js processes (I  would like to manage them through pm2). I also want to manage sticky sessions to this multiple node.js processes. How should I do that? Should I do it using two containers (node.js + nginx) or put them in one container somehow?

I suspect if using multiple containers I need to use docker-compose but will I be able do that with ECS?

Comment: On ECS you can run docker-compose. Why do you want multiple node js containers ?

Comment: for scaling purposes

Comment: How can I run docker-compose in ECS?

Comment: Install docker-compose then just run it e.g. docker-compose up -d

If you want to scale you are better off looking at docker swarm or Kubernetes, so you can scale according to load.

Comment: Thanks! So you say that for scaling in production I would better use [ECS for Kubernetes](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/eks/?nc2=h_m1) or simply Kuberenetes?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. Yet to do it myself. I think you can install a single node Kubernetes set up in development to see how it all works. Have fun !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good practice is to have two containers and use docker-compose.
About ECS please check here, they propose their own stuff and maybe you'd like it
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html